# Git set upstream doesn't work

Tags: git

I'm trying to set my git repo to have set-upstream on my branches, but it's not working.

My .git/config looks like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://cjdawson@new.initialreality.com:22/git-repos/webmessage/server/java/webmessage-server.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
    push = HEAD:refs/for/master
    pushurl = ssh://cjdawson@new.initialreality.com:22/git-repos/webmessage/server/java/webmessage-server.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[gerrit]
    createchangeid = true
[push]
    default = upstream
```

And when I run `git remote show origin` I get:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://cjdawson@new.initialreality.com:22/git-repos/webmessage/server/java/webmessage-server.git
  Push  URL: ssh://cjdawson@new.initialreality.com:22/git-repos/webmessage/server/java/webmessage-server.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop tracked
    master  tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop merges with remote develop
    master  merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    HEAD pushes to refs/for/master (up to date)
```

If I run `git push origin develop` or `git branch -u origin/develop`, the output of show origin does not change. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there were files in my remote repository (not sure how they got there) and they were creating issues. After removing them, things seemed to work now.

Comment: I had the same issue, everything runs fine in the terminal. But if call the pull action or Sync action from the VS Code, it says upstream was not set. Nothing changed after I set it.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `git remote show` is misleading, but you already have the upstream branches configured, you can see them in "Local branches configured for 'git pull'".

Personally I use `git branch -vv` to see the upstream tracking branch of each branch.

Comment: I see. but git push still doesn't work. It claims everything is up-to-date but git status shows my code ahead by one commit.

Comment: @shadowayex Perhaps you are on a branch other than `master` or `develop`, then (or maybe even no branch)?